# Get element in puppeteer to be used in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer

I am making tests for my project and am using jest and puppeteer for e2e testing. I need to get raw elements from the page and run jquery operations on it.

I have already tried:

```js
var temp = await page.$eval(modal1, (e) => $(e).text());
```

but I need:

```js
var temp = await page.$eval(modal1, (e) => $(e));
var tempText = temp.text();
```

When I try this I get an undefined object.

Comment: You won't be able to do that. `eval` returns `serializables` objects (string, numbers, json objects) and a jQuery element is not serializable. There is nothing wrong with option 1.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Maybe you can give some context?